# Simple news ticker - how to make autoscroll / auto action performe with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I wrote small news ticker, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/MrTest/SvFRs/

I would like to add to it - auto scroll ( perform click on 'next' every couple of seconds).
Also, how can I prevent script of doing it if user have interact with it within let say less than 5 sec or currently on hover?

Unfortunately,  I don't have a clue how I could start. Any clues?

Any help much appreciated.

Pete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SvFRs/57/)**

Below is the code I changed. Basically all you do is assign a `timeout` to an interval id, and then clear it when you don't want it to change, and reset it when you do.

```
// Set a timeout
var timeOut = setTimeout(nextNotice, 3000);

// pause on hover
$('.noticeboard').hover(
    function(){clearTimeout(timeOut);},
    function(){timeOut = setTimeout(nextNotice, 3000);}
)
// Next notice function called on timeout or click
function nextNotice(event){
    clearTimeout(timeOut);
    timeOut = setTimeout(nextNotice, 3000);

    if ($('.noticeboard span:visible').is('.noticeboard span:last-child')) {
        $('.noticeboard span:visible').fadeOut();
        $('.noticeboard span:first-child').fadeIn();
    }
    else {
        $('.noticeboard span:visible').fadeOut().next().fadeIn();
    }

    if(event){
        event.preventDefault(); 
    }
}


$('#notice-next').click(nextNotice);
```

Comment: @Loktar Great! Thanks! Is working perfectly forward, but seam there is a problem with 'prev'. JSLINT is throwing an error.

Comment: Also, firebug is saying that: event.preventDefault();
 not a function? Why??

Comment: @Pete not sure about the prev issue, I didnt touch that part of the code at all as you didnt need prev to automatically scroll. Event isnt getting passed via the setTimeout only on click, thats why your getting the preventDefault error.

Comment: try changing the call to `$('#notice-next').click(nextNotice(e));`

Comment: @ianbarker click was passing the event, this issue was when the setTimeout was calling nextNotice that no event was being passed. I just put in a simple fix to only preventDefault if the event was actually being passed.

Answer (score 1):

the best way would be to make your next and previous events into functions. Then you can use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/window.setInterval) to call the next function. You'll need to keep a count so that when you get to the end you can show the first one again. You can stop the ticker using clearInterval.

Hope that helps point you in the correct direction.

Comment: You should link to this one instead https://developer.mozilla.org/En/window.setInterval

Comment: yeah, that's the one I was looking for but w3schools came up in Google first

Comment: Go [here](http://www.google.com/preferences?hl=en) and add it to your blocked sites, it's the best feeling in the world!

Comment: Thanks, I remember reading about being able to do that but I never got around to doing it. Bye bye BigResource too!